# Magento pass and save additional details from cart page into orders table

Tags: magento

I need to pass some additional parameters along eith the products from Cart page and save it to order table whenever an order is being placed.For example the parameterscould be a custom price or anything.

I have created the DB field in the table "sales_flat_order_item".

Which is the best way to accomplish the above requirement ?

1) Save the additional parameters when the order is being placed using "sales_order_place_before" event

2) Save the details in quote before proceeding to checkout

Moreover which event would be used if I save the details before proceeding to checkout ?

I can not think of the best way to achieve this.

Please Help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look @ http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/19344/

In config.xml

```
...
<global> 
     <fieldsets>
        <sales_convert_quote>                           
            <cs_aoc_webid><to_order>*</to_order></cs_aoc_webid>
        </sales_convert_quote>

        <sales_convert_order>                                              
            <cs_aoc_webid><to_quote>*</to_quote></cs_aoc_webid>
        </sales_convert_order>
    </fieldsets>

 ....
    <events>
        <some add to cart event>
            <observers>
                <adminorderconfirmation>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>customquotefields/observer</class>
                    <method>saveData</method>
                </adminorderconfirmation>
            </observers>
        </some add to cart event>
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. The steps would be

1) Define your quote item details along with event and observer using above XML
        
2) Implement your business logic and set data

3) Rest will be done by Magento